# Referring back to a 'duo'

Tags: grammar, reference

Quick question:

"The duo known as Pin Up Club owes its name to..."

In this sentence, am I correctly referring to 'the duo' with '**its** name'? Or should this be '**their** name'?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What flavour of English would you like? I believe the answer to this question is different in American English to British English.

Comment: Depends on the context.  "It's" is probably slightly more idiomatic in the average case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which one you want to highlight. If you want to give stress to the group's name, use "its", but if you previously stated or stressed them as two individuals, use "their".

Comment: ... and is this answer for American or British?

Comment: @GEdgar I think that alleged/so-called difference is overstated. Just as companies almost always take *their*, so too do couples.  “The couple is/are picking out *their* wedding cake” no matter whether you say *is* or *are* . And that choice is not wholly determined by where you live.